# How can I get rid of the "Are you sure you want to leave this page" message?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, opera

How can I get rid of the "Are you sure you want to leave this page" message?

I try to use `window.onBeforeunload=null` and it works for Chrome, but it did not work for Firefox, Internet Explorer and Opera.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you seeing this?  Is this a page you wrote?  If so, can you post some relevant code?

Comment: `window.,onBeforeunload=null` is invalid syntax btw. Probably just a typo in your post, but if you ask a question, please take the time to make sure that the information you provide is correct.

Comment: how is `beforeunload` working Opera at all?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure why your script is working in Chrome, all browsers should behave in the same way with this. Is it possible, that the code block where you remove the event listener, is for some reason executed only in Chrome?

Anyway, if you set `window.onbeforeunload = someFunction;` you can nullify it with `window.onbeforeunload = null`. However, if you set `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', someFunction);`, this event listener can't be removed with `window.onbeforeunload = null`. It can be removed only with `removeEventListener('beforeunload', someFunction);`.

If this answer doesn't help, please post all relevant code, like the snippet when assigning event listener, and also when trying to remove it.

Comment: $attrs = array('onchange' => 'javascript:this.form.submit();window.onbeforeunload=null;onUnload=null');
                $mform->addElement('select', 'teacher', 'Teachers', $result, $attrs);

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery

```
$(window).off('beforeunload'); // tested in IE 11 and Chrome 62
```

Comment: I was unsuccessful using the accepted answer, and jQuery was already available on the page.

Answer (score -13):

Clear my browsing history, seemed to help.